# ForEach Move Next special situation

Tags: powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Hello I have the following code, with three functions

```
function Search_User_File { foreach  ($User in $FILE) { Search_User_AD} }

function Search_User_AD {
    $Ad = Get-ADUser -filter * -Properties sAMAccountName,sn,givenName,department,title,telephoneNumber,employeeID,employeeNumber  -SearchBase "OU=COMPANY,DC=COMPANYcolo,DC=pvt" | Select-Object  sAMAccountName,sn,givenName,department,title,telephoneNumber,employeeID,employeeNumber
    $Search = $Ad | ? {$_.sn -eq $User.sn}
    If ($Search) {
        Foreach ($AD_User in $Search)  {
              Write-Host "=============CSV User==============="
              Write-Host ""
              Write-Host "=============AD User==============="
              Write-Host ""
              $RightWrong = Read-Host 'Is this the RIGHT EMPLOYEE we are working (Y/N)'
              If ($RightWrong -eq "Y") {
        write-host ""
        $Correct = Read-Host 'NOTE: Is the EMPLOYEE Information FOUND In AD CORRECT AGAINST The EMPLOYEE Information FOUND In the FILE File? (Y/N)'
        If (($RightWrong -eq "Y") -and ($Correct -eq "N")){
            Edit_AD_User
        }
        Elseif (($RightWrong -eq "Y") -and ($Correct -eq "Y"))  {
                            clear-host
```

> RIGHT HERE, HOW DO I MOVE.NEXT ON SEARCH_USER_FILE ?
> IF I DO NOT DO IT, THEN  Search_User_File IS GOING TO START ALL OVER.

```
                            Search_User_File
        }
   }
}

function Edit_User_AD {

}

$File = Import-Csv "c:\scripts\ad\temp\file.csv" -header sn,givenName,department,title,telephoneNumber,employeeID,employeeNumber
Search_User_File
```

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty inefficient, as you're retrieving everyone in AD every time and then searching on surname. If at all possible, get something that will uniquely identify each user in that CSV file so you can filter within the `Get-ADUser` cmdlet, instead of after the fact.

What happens if you have 2 users with the same surname (`sn`)?

Typically what you would want to do is search AD for the user, find them, assign that object to a variable, then perform your edits & then save the changes. You're kind of bouncing around a bit here.

```
$File = Import-Csv "c:\scripts\ad\temp\file.csv" -header sn,givenName,department,title,telephoneNumber,employeeID,employeeNumber

foreach ($user in $file) {
  Search_User_AD $user.sn
}

function Search_User_AD {
param(
 [string]$sn
)
    $Ad = Get-ADUser -filter * -Properties sAMAccountName,sn,givenName,department,title,telephoneNumber,employeeID,employeeNumber  -SearchBase "OU=COMPANY,DC=COMPANYcolo,DC=pvt" | Select-Object  sAMAccountName,sn,givenName,department,title,telephoneNumber,employeeID,employeeNumber
    $Search = $Ad | ? {$sn -eq $User.sn}
    If ($Search) {
        Foreach ($AD_User in $Search)  {
              Write-Host "=============CSV User==============="
              Write-Host ""
              Write-Host "=============AD User==============="
              Write-Host ""
              $RightWrong = Read-Host 'Is this the RIGHT EMPLOYEE we are working (Y/N)'
              If ($RightWrong -eq "Y") {
        write-host ""
        $Correct = Read-Host 'NOTE: Is the EMPLOYEE Information FOUND In AD CORRECT AGAINST The EMPLOYEE Information FOUND In the FILE File? (Y/N)'
        If (($RightWrong -eq "Y") -and ($Correct -eq "N")){
            Edit_AD_User
        }
        Elseif (($RightWrong -eq "Y") -and ($Correct -eq "Y"))  {
                            clear-host
        }
     }
   }
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply, if there are 2 users with the same surname (sn),the code will display the user on AD and User from CSV file and will ask, "is the whole information correct ?" if not AD jumps to the next possible user with a unique last name